# Xcode link with glew error

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, cmake, glew

I'm trying to write a project using OpenGL 4.1. I usually switch between Windows and OS X. On Windows I use Visual Studio 2013 making the project using cmake. This works just fine. On OS X, when I use cmake with -G "Unix Makefiles" I can compile and run just fine. However, if i generate an Xcode project, Xcode fails building with the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lglew
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using this CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(Framework)

set(SRC_FILES src/shader.cpp  
              src/framework.cpp                 
              src/fileio.cpp    
              src/scene.cpp   
              src/renderable.cpp   
              src/camera.cpp  
              src/mesh.cpp   
              src/material.cpp 
              src/light.cpp 
              src/triangle.cpp 
              src/cube.cpp 
              src/basicshader.cpp
              src/frameworkmodel.cpp
              src/texture.cpp
              )

set(HEADER_FILES include/shader.h 
                 include/framework.h
                 include/fileio.h
                 include/scene.h
                 include/renderable.h
                 include/camera.h 
                 include/mesh.h   
                 include/material.h 
                 include/light.h 
                 include/triangle.h
                 include/cube.h
                 include/basicshader.h
                 include/frameworkmodel.h
                 include/texture.h
                 )



if (WIN32)
  list(APPEND SRC_FILES src/GLee.cpp src/glew.cpp)
  list(APPEND HEADER_FILES include/GLee.h include/glew.h)
endif()

if (APPLE)
  SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "-framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -lglew")
endif()

set(GLFW_PATH glfw-3.1)
set(SOIL_PATH SOIL)

add_subdirectory(${GLFW_PATH})


include_directories(${GLFW_PATH}/include)
include_directories(${SOIL_PATH})

file(GLOB SOIL_SRC
    "${SOIL_PATH}/*.h"
    "${SOIL_PATH}/*.c"
)

include_directories(./include)

add_library(soil ${SOIL_SRC})

add_library(framework ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(framework soil)

add_executable(test01 tests/test01.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test01 framework)
target_link_libraries(test01 glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(test01 glfw ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(test01 glfw ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS})
```

Is there something obviously wrong with this?

**SOLUTION**

I found the .dylib location of my glew installation and added it to the xcode search path, works just as it should.

Comment: On windows you add both the glew.h and glew.cpp from the library, right? So it compiles directly into your program. However I don't see exactly why the UNIX makefiles would work.

Comment: I added the glew files for windows compilation since it seemed easier than installing it. On OS X I have glew installed, so the makefile links with the installed glew, and somehow, Xcode seems not to.

Comment: My guess is that make also uses directories such as /usr/lib etc, but Xcode doesn't search these paths by itself? Maybe you can try to add /usr/lib, or where it is installed to the gcc flags using -Ldir, so -L"usr/lib".